# Chrome only works in private mode

Tags: google-chrome, 21.10

Installed chrome .deb from official google site. It only works in private mode.

Sites keep loading forever in non-private mode.

I have no extensions and haven't changed anything in the settings.

Comment: Have you try clearing cache/cookies or reinstalling it?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new profile, go into home folder ctrl + h to show hidden folders. Navigate to ./config inside the folder there will be a Google Chrome folder, delete that folder and relaunch Chrome.

Comment: That doesn't work.